# Баг с CSS колонками в IE11

Tags: css, hover, width

Здравствуйте, имеется баг с отображением колонок с помощью проперти **columns**/**column-width**. 
Суть в том, что первый эелемент второго и последующих столбцов, залазит в предыдущий столбец в IE11 (скорее всего и в 10 тоже самое):

```css
.test {
 columns: 4; 
}

.test > a {
  display: block;
}

.test > a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="" >1</a>
  <a href="" >2</a>
  <a href="" >3</a>
  <a href="" >4</a>
  <a href="" >5</a>
  <a href="" >6</a>
  <a href="" >7</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vav84qb4/1/

Может кто знает как можно пофиксить этот баг, желательно без js и сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.test {
  columns: 4; 
}

.test > a {
  display: block;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.test > a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="" >1</a>
  <a href="" >2</a>
  <a href="" >3</a>
  <a href="" >4</a>
  <a href="" >5</a>
  <a href="" >6</a>
  <a href="" >7</a>
</div>
```