# Проблема с min-height и column-width в Safari 10-

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с Safari версии ниже 10 (10.0.1 - включительно)
Имеется выпадающий список, который, с помощью column-width, разделен на несколько колонок. Также имеется свойство min-height(его нужно оставить) для задания минимальной высоты блока со списком. Во всех браузерах кроме Safari 10- - список отображается верное (был баг на IE - [Баг с CSS колонками в IE11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731409/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81-css-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-ie11))
Быть может, кто-нибудь знает, как можно обойти данную проблему. Как я понимаю - проблема только в min-height.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  column-width: 100px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

.child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>  
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
  <a href="" class="child">123</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для старых браузеров добавьте свойство ширины колонки с префиксами:

```
-moz-column-width: 100px;
-webkit-column-width: 100px;
```

Comment: Извините, но ваш способ не работает. Тут, скорее, баг не с самими колонками, а с колонками + минимальная высота, без нее, все работает прекрасно, но ее нужно оставить, причем, желательно, исправить это только css-ом.